# Eclipse automated code formation and Hyperlinks

Tags: eclipse, coding-style

I'm a big fan of the automated code formation (STRG + SHIFT + F) from eclipse. It makes your code so much more readable. However, now that I'm comenting my code, I'm getting the problem with Hyperlinks. Code formation adds line breaks anywhere in your code, so if you have e.g. a very long hyperlink it breaks into multiple lines and makes it unresolvable :(

Is there a way that eclipse doesn't format specific comment parts like Hyperlinks?

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Try using http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_cdt_core_CodeFormatter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way from setting that up in the menu. The workaround is to disable block or line comment formatting in the formatter profile:

**Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit -> tab Comments**

As pointed out by Kheldar, you can always customise/extend the Java Codeformatter using the extension point, but that's probably not a one hour job for someone unfamiliar with the JDT.
Please indicate, if you need any assistance coding an extension for the formatter.

Comment: thanks, there I also found the "<pre>..</pre>" tag which actually does ecactly what I was serching for (leave links alone and format code as code). thanks

Comment: Good to know. I wasn't sure whether you were referring to JavaDoc or normal comments...

Answer (score 2):

Code formating doesn't put line breaks in links inside `a` tags:

```
<a href=
"http://www.example.com/very-long-url">Example</a>
```

There is a line break just after the `href=`, so it may look ugly in a paragraph. Enclosing urls in `<tt>` tags prevents line breaks, but the url won't be a clickable link. Combine both and you get hyperlinks without line breaks. If they exceed the maximum line length, they will start on a new line though.

```
  <tt><a href="http://www.example.com/very-long-url">Example</a></tt>
```

There is also `//@formatter:off` to disable formatting for the following lines and `//@formatter:on` to enable it again.